# How to retrieve object from JSON in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, promise

Having this code:

```
const fs = require('fs')

const file = 'books.json';

class Book{
  constructor(code) {
    this._code = code;
  }

  get code() {
    return this._code;
  }

  set code(value) {
    this._code = value;
  }
}

async function writeBooks(){
  const data = JSON.stringify([new Book('c1'), new Book('c2')]);
  await fs.promises.writeFile(file, data, 'utf8');
}

async function getBook(code){
  try{
    const data = await fs.promises.readFile(file);
    const array = JSON.parse(data);
    return array.find(b => b.code === code);
  } catch (err){
    console.log(err)
  }
}

writeBooks();
getBook('c1').then(b => console.log(b));
```

I am getting `undefined` (instead of the expecting book object).

1. How to get the object (the above problem)
2. If `async` function always returns promise, how can I then return object for the client, instead of him having to call `then()` from the `getBook(code)`?
3. do I need to `await` for the `fs.promises.writeFile()`? as I am doing in `writeBooks()`? As fas as I understand the `async/await` now, is that the return value from `await` function is the data or error. But since the `writeFile()` does not returns anything, or error at most (as opposed to `readFile()`) why would I want to `await` for no data?

Comment: You need to wait for `writeBooks` to finish writing to file _before_ you read the file.

Comment: @Yousaf how to do so?

Comment: [Example](https://pastebin.com/LWBUbPiw)

Answer (score 1):

Actually the root of problem is not about async/awaits or promises. The problem is trying to write an array to a json file. If you write your json data like the code snippet below (as a key-value pair), your problem is solved.

```html
{"1": [new Book('c1').code, new Book('c2').code]} //as a key-value pair
```

```html
const fs = require('fs')
const file = 'books.json';
class Book{
  constructor(code) {
    this._code = code;
  }
  get code() {
    return this._code;
  }
  set code(value) {
    this._code = value;
  }
}
async function writeBooks(){
  const data = JSON.stringify({"1": [new Book('c1').code, new Book('c2').code]});
  await fs.promises.writeFile(file, data, 'utf8');
}
async function getBook(code){
  try{
    const data = await fs.promises.readFile(file);
    const dataOnJsonFile = JSON.parse(data);
    return dataOnJsonFile["1"];
  } catch (err){
    console.log(err)
  }
}
writeBooks();
getBook('c1').then(b => console.log(b));
```

Comment: What you did is just added name for the array inside the object to be stored in JSON. But you misunderstood the `getBook(code)` method: in your code, you just returns the whole array, that is possible even without the named array (as in my original post). But what I do not understand is why, after obtaining the array, I cannot select only the one, based on `code`: `array.find(b => b.code === code)`. When debugging, I am correctly gainig the array from JSON, but I cannot somehow select only the one. So your answer does not target my question

Answer (score 0):

1. The above problem is that the Books returned from `JSON.parse` have only data, not methods, and thus I cannot get the `code` via `get code(){}`, but only as public parameter of class `Book` as `book._code`, which however breaks encapsulation (convetion is that `_[propery]` is private, and there should be appropriate getters/setters). So I made the properties public (and broke encapsulation), because I still don't know, how to assign methods to object created from JSON.
2. No, the result of `async` is always Promise. You cannot unwrap it inside `async`, the client will always have to unwrap it. (so `await fs.promises.WriteFile()` will unwrap it, but then immediately wrap it back, before async function returns.
3. as explained above.